# .bat script to Search all drives for existing subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

Currently I have this:

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
   if exist "%%d\Program Files (x86)\Folder": (
        cd "%%d\Program Files (x86)\Folder\subfolder\file"
         )
)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I want the batch script to search the drives for the existence of a certain program's subfolder, then cd to the location of a .ini file if it does. The file may also be in a location other than /program files/, i.e. it might be on driveletter:\Folder.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you have `programfiles(x86)` and `programfiles` variables and you do not need to traverse all letters...

Comment: I'm putting this in the comments because you specifically asked for a `.bat` file, but I'd encourage you to consider [tag:powershell] instead.

Comment: The file may not be located in either of those, this is an example.

Comment: Powershell is not allowed on these machines for security reasons :( If it was I would be using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code:

- The colon belongs after the drive letter.
- You must use the /D option if your CD command is changing the active drive.
- Your logic will fail if "folder" turns out to be a file name instead of a folder name
- You never bother to verify that subfolder exists
- You cannot CD to a file as your pseudo code implies

The following changes should work:

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\subfolder\" (
    cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\subfolder"
  )
)
```

But there is a better way - you can simply attempt to CD without verifying the existence of the folder, and redirect any error message to null.

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\subfolder" 2>nul
)
```

If you want to detect whether the CD was ultimately successful, then you can use `&&` to conditionally break out of the loop, so that the ERRORLEVEL will be 0 upon success, or 1 upon failure.

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\subfolder" 2>nul && goto :break
)
:break
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo SUCCESS
) else (
  echo FAILURE
)
```

Besides detecting succuess/error, there is another difference with the last option if the subfolder exists on two different drive. The first two options ultimately CD to the last found subfolder. The last option does a CD to the first found subfolder.

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you!

Quick question: If the folder is not in program files\folder and is instead on %%d:\folder, would it make sense to just put in this loop again or can I do a conditional check for both possible locations?

Comment: You could try it yourself and see what happens ;-) You should try out various test conditions (intentionally create various test scenarios) before you jump to conclusions. I would put two CD /D commands within a single loop. You could use either form, with or without the conditional GOTO :BREAK.

Comment: I came up with something that works, then prompts the user for the correct install location if it can't find it. Now I need to figure out how to resolve the prompt correctly...

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist "%programfiles(x86)%\Folder\subfolder\file" (

    echo it's alive!

)
```

is this working? Why do you traverse all these letters?

Comment: I need to search every drive and may not know what all drives exist on the machine it will be running on. Based on the returned response, I need to CD to the folder on the correct drive.

The folder will not exist on any other drive because it is an install location--I need to determine which drive a program was installed to.

Comment: @VioletSmith - %SYSTEMDRIVE% will point to the drive where the program files are.

Comment: In this use case the directory where the files are located may not be the program files folder. It could also be in F:\Folder\files for example.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you should use environment variables to access the program files folder, so you don't have to check for the existing drives.

Take a look at http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html or enter `set` in the command prompt.

In your case you should use `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`

Comment: Would this work if the file existed in (driveletter)\Folder? So it would be %folder\subfolder\file